# Inconsistent values of useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I'm in process of creating first user signup form and I'm now experiencing something that is beyond my skills and seems to be pretty easy to fix. It's all about one helperText for MUI select component that doesn't render as it should. Let me explain:

I have 2 objects "values" and "errors".

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
firstName: "",
lastName: "",
password: "",
passwordRetype: "",
profession: "",
telephone: "",
verificationCode: "",
showPassword: false,
});

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
firstName: false,
lastName: false,
password: false,
passwordRetype: false,
profession: false,
telephone: false,
verificationCode: false,
});
```

I also have very simple validation form. (console.logs are only for debugging)

```
const validateForms = (step) => {
if (step === 1) {
  if (values.firstName.length < 3) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.firstName = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.firstName = false));
  if (values.lastName.length < 3) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.lastName = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.lastName = false));
  if (values.password.length < 8) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.password = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.password = false));
  if (values.passwordRetype !== values.password) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.passwordRetype = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.passwordRetype = false));
  if (!values.profession) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.profession = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.profession = false));
}
if (step === 2) {
  if (values.telephone.length != 9) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.telephone = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.telephone = false));
  if (values.verificationCode != verificationCode) {
    setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.verificationCode = true));
  } else setErrors({ ...errors }, (errors.verificationCode = false));
}
console.log("errors object");
console.log(errors);
console.log("values object");
console.log(values);
};
```

Now I have every helperText working as expected beside one for profession Select component which can be seen below.

```
 <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="professionSelect">Profesja</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="professionSelect"
            id="professionSelect"
            error={errors.profession}
            value={values.profession}
            onChange={handleValueChange("profession")}
            label="Profesja"
          >
            <MenuItem value="elektryk">Elektryk</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="hydraulik">Hydraulik</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          {errors.profession ? (
            <FormHelperText error id="professionSelect">
              Musisz wybrać profesję.
            </FormHelperText>
          ) : (
            console.log(
              `errors.profession inside return is ${errors.profession}`
            )
          )}
        </FormControl>
```

So the result of console.logs is as below:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1edTz.png)

As you can see, while errors.profession is set to "true" (and that's correct as no profession was selected) it seems that it changes state during rendering.

What I have tried:

1. set Select helperText condition to "if (!values.profession) " - it shows helper properly but it is visible as early as page renders
   which is not correct
2. set helperText condition to any other error value than profession (eg. errors.password) - works perfectly... but you know I want to have this helper related to Select value, not password or firstName :)
3. changed name from error.profession to error.professionTest - did not work...

I have run out of ideas. Seems like something is resetting error.profession but the only time I use setErrors is in the validation function.

EDIT 1: I forgot to add: whenever I set profession to any value it let's me move to next step of sign up. However, when no profession is selected, next step of signup is not rendered. This may prove that errors.profession is indeed set to false only after selecting profession.

EDIT 2: I can also add very similar code that works just perfectly fine for password validation. There is no big difference between them and one works, the other one don't.

```
        <FormControl sx={{}} variant="outlined" fullWidth>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Hasło</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            fullWidth
            value={values.password}
            error={errors.password}
            helperText={
              errors.password
                ? "Hasło musi składać się z co najmniej 8 znaków"
                : ""
            }
            type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            onChange={handleValueChange("password")}
            id="password"
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
            label="Hasło"
          />
          {errors.password ? (
            <FormHelperText error id="password">
              Hasło musi składać się z co najmniej 8 znaków
            </FormHelperText>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </FormControl>
```

Comment: Logging directly after calling `set...` is not reliable since state is not set synchronously

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Select
            labelId="professionSelect"
            id="professionSelect"
            error={errors.profession}
            value={values.profession}
            onChange={handleValueChange("profession")}
            label="Profesja"
          >
```

in line

```
onChange={handleValueChange("profession")}
```

you call the method `handleValueChange`. If you want to trigger it on actual change:

```
onChange={e => handleValueChange("profession")}
```

I don't know what is inside of this method but you will probably need to pass the value you've changed to this method.

```
onChange={e => handleValueChange("profession", e.target.value)}
```

Comment: handleValueChange looks like that: 

    const handleValueChange = (prop) => (event) => {
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    };

Comment: @TomaszMarczak, then this should work: `onChange={e => handleValueChange("profession")(e)}`

Comment: @Aditya that's unneeded. The OP's code is fine. This answer sadly doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: But ValueChange works fine all the time. The problem is that I cannot access errors.profession in one spot. I changed onChange to what you suggested and unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Change the way you set errors here:

```if (!values.profession) {
    setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, profession: true}));
  } else setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, profession: false}));```

Comment: It worked! I have just checked it and at first glance it looks like its working. I will test further against other bugs I had in my code. Thank you for commitment!